# Performance will be better using CSOM or REST API to retrieve data from 4 lists simultaneously.?

Tags: performance, rest, sharepoint, csom, office365-apps

I am developing **Sharepoint hosted app**, and there is a situation where i need to get the data from 4 lists simultaneously, then use it later on. I am able to do it using **CSOM**. But performance wise what will be better **CSOM** or **REST API**. If rest API is the better approach then how can i do it.?

Answer (score 5):

My approach for SharePoint-hosted add-in is to use

a. REST API when requesting:

- Single Element / Single Collection retrieval (single List, single ListColletion, single ListItem, single ListItemCollection, single Field, single FieldCollection etc.)
- Large Datasets
- Two things to consider when using REST API:
- i. I do prefer using `sp.RequestExecutor.js` to executeQueryAsync over $Ajax calls. Reason #1: developing addins that interacts with other Site Collections or sibling webs. Reason #2: your `X-RequestDigest` header is resolved natively.
- ii. Choose wisely your odata value in the `Accept: application/json; odata=?` header. `odata=verbose` is, well, verbose, meaning that it returns A LOT of generally unuseful metadata information that slow down responses. `odata=mininalmetadata` is a good choice for when you need a single metadatata information. `odata=nometadata` is what you generally need. Note that the object returned varies. While in verbose mode: `obj.body.d.results`. For the two other methods, `obj.body.value`

b. I use JSOM API when I need to:

- Request ==at once== more than one List or ListItem, or need to load into the context different elements.
- Batch updates

[image: REST odata variation]
References:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brian_farnhill/2014/03/11/approaches-to-optimising-sharepoint-client-side-communication/

http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/sharepoint-2013-csom-vs.-rest-...-my-preference-and-why

http://blog.mannsoftware.com/?p=1521

https://blogs.office.com/2014/08/13/json-light-support-rest-sharepoint-api-released/

http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/overview/

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn168907.aspx

http://www.vrdmn.com/2013/07/batch-operations-using-javascript.html

Answer (score 1):

I invite you to read this article :
http://blog.mannsoftware.com/?p=1521

In my understanding, REST shows better performance. In time response time, it's about 30% shorter.

And how to dot it ?
With Ajax, it's quite easy. Here is an example which show how to use it :

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nickpinheiro/archive/2015/01/30/build-a-sharepoint-hosted-app-to-access-list-data-in-your-host-web-using-the-rest-api-in-10-easy-steps.aspx